Azure DevOps REST API Downloading an NPM artifact
I'm trying to download a NPM artifact from an Azure DevOps feed within the pipeline
As for any other tasks I do this over python using a syntax similar to the following:
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + "$(System.AccessToken)")]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

url = f"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedId}/npm/packages/{packageName}/versions/{packageVersion}/content?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, target)

As mentioned above, the token works on any other api calls. I can easily download pipeline artifacts, read-out feed properties and so on. However, for the above I get "401".
If I paste the URL into my browser, where I'm logged in, then the download starts correctly - so the URL seems to be OK.
I've tried to get another token by creating a .npmrc file and vsts-npm-auth. However, also with this token I get the same output. To me it looks like either a setting in Azure is to be made, or some other request procedure is wrong.
Do you have any hints for me? Thanks!

Hi @Nico, testing in my pipeline, the scripts work whether passing the predefined variable System.AccessToken or a PAT to access_token. Have you pass the token via an environment variable in PythonScript@0 task? What's the result if you directly pass a PAT to SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN?

To download NPM packages using REST API Npm - Download Package in python, you can refer to the followings.

Assign your build service account with the Feed Reader role of your target feed.
When you use System.AccessToken for authentication, the identity used to access your feed is a build service account.
If your project has enabled "Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines" from Project Settings -> Pipeline Settings, the build service account used is project-scoped. Otherwise, it's collection-scoped.

Go to your feed -> Feed Settings -> Permissions -> Add users or groups. Assign the corresponding build service account with Feed Reader role.

The collection-scoped build service account name has format: Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName})
The project-scoped build service account name has format: {Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name})



Add a PythonScript@0 task and pass System.AccessToken via the environment variable. For example,


pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath'
    scriptPath: 'test.py'

- script: ls -l
  displayName: 'List all the files in the current dir'


The test.py: Read the token via the environment variable SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN.

import urllib.request
import os

# Define your variables
organization = '{YourOrg}'
project = '{YourProj}'
feedId = '{YourFeed}'

access_token = os.getenv('SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN')

# Construct the URL
url = f'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedId}/npm/packages/@adobe%2Fcss-tools/versions/4.3.3/content?api-version=7.1-preview.1'

# Create a password manager
password_mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_mgr.add_password(None, url, '', access_token)

# Create an opener
handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)

# Install the opener
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

# Download the package
output_file = 'css-tools-4.3.3.tgz'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, output_file)

print(f'Package downloaded and saved as {output_file}')


Result: The package is downloaded in the current working directory.




Hi. Thanks for the detailed reply. At least locally I could make it work successfully with your method and the HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm thingy instead of the authorization bearer. BUT one thing was relevant and also little confusing to me. The Access token string I have to use is the bare raw access token and not base64 encoded version of it... Unfortunately, within the pipeline I cannot make it work yet. Still 401


Didn't you use the predefined variable System.AccessToken in the Azure DevOps pipeline? Testing in my pipeline, the scripts work whether passing the predefined variable System.AccessToken or a PAT to access_token. 2. Please go to Project Settings -> Pipeline Settings, check whether "Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines" option is enabled or not. If this option is turned on, please turn it off.



Have you assigned correct build service account with the Feed Reader role of your target feed? When you run the scripts locally, the identity used is the one corresponding to your PAT instead of the build service account.


Thanks for the help. Both seems to be correctly set and I could not resolve the issue. I managed to reach my goal by implementing a workaround that uses NpmAuthenticate, then npm install and then I simply packed the package again.. Not nice, but at least this works

Hi @Nico, thanks for your update. To help others who may have the same issue, it would be better if you could post an answer to share your workaround with more details. Or I can help you update your workaround in the answer above.
